Finding close vertices in a pointcloud with specific labels
I have 3D vertices of an object;
I'm trying to ensure vertices with labels of 1 are not too close to vertices with label 2.
I intend for such vertex pairs to be remapped to label 0.
Doing this in a loop is incredibly slow, so I tried using cdists but the labels don't get updated:
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
import numpy as np
# ...
# configure the labels
labels = np.zeros(len(vertices), dtype=int)
labels[left_mask] = 1
labels[right_mask] = 2

threshold = 2

distances = cdist(vertices[left_mask], vertices[right_mask]) # finds all distances

close_vertices = np.any(distances < threshold, axis=1) # finds all indices below threshold 
labels[left_mask][close_vertices] = 0 # this doesn't update labels

distances = cdist(vertices[right_mask], vertices[left_mask])
close_vertices = np.any(distances < threshold, axis=1)
labels[right_mask][close_vertices] = 0 # this doesn't update labels

The issue is that labels[right_mask][close_vertices] seems to create a copy/view, so the original labels don't change at all.
How would I reference labels using the mask and then from these selected by the mask, those who are close.
Here's a minimal example - all the points in the middle should be changed to label 0(red) because they're too close to the blue points.

# Create random vertices in different ranges
vertices_left = np.random.rand(15, 3)
labels_left = np.zeros(15, dtype=int) + 1

vertices_middle = np.random.rand(15, 3) + 1
labels_middle = np.zeros(15, dtype=int) + 1

vertices_right = np.random.rand(15, 3) + 2
labels_right = np.zeros(15, dtype=int) + 2

# Combine all vertices and labels
vertices = np.vstack((vertices_left, vertices_middle, vertices_right))
labels = np.concatenate((labels_left, labels_middle, labels_right))

# Map labels to colors: 0 => red, 1 => green
colors = np.array(['red', 'green', 'blue'])
vertex_colors = colors[labels]

# Plot the vertices
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(vertices[:, 0], vertices[:, 1], vertices[:, 2], c=vertex_colors)

# Show the plot
plt.show()


This example appears to only show green and blue points.

Please include left_mask and right_mask in your example.

Generate a mask from close_vertices. Then simply do np.logical_and(left_mask, close_mask).
